# Silverlight - DataTable

Tags: silverlight

I have a need to basically create a matrix of values in my Silverlight 3 application. Is there anything equivalent to a DataTable that I could store a matrix of values within?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I'm unsure of its use... could a simple multidimensional array work?

```
int[,] myArray = new int[4,2];
myArray[2,1] = 25;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the List collection for this purpose,

```
private List<Employee> populatedlistEmployee()
        {
            listEmployee = new List<Employee>();
            listEmployee.Add(new Employee() { ID = 1, FirstName = "Khalid", LastName = "Rafique", City = "ISB", FatherName = "Muhammad Rafique", PhoneNo = "092-333-5494532", Status = true });
            listEmployee.Add(new Employee() { ID = 2, FirstName = "Awais", LastName = "Ahmed", City = "isb", FatherName = "Ahmed", PhoneNo = "--", Status = false });
            listEmployee.Add(new Employee() { ID = 3, FirstName = "Ali", LastName = "hasan", City = "Rwp", FatherName = "Hasan ahmed", PhoneNo = "--", Status = false });
            listEmployee.Add(new Employee() { ID = 4, FirstName = "Hasan", LastName = "khan", City = "Lha", FatherName = "Ali ahmed", PhoneNo = "--", Status = false });
            listEmployee.Add(new Employee() { ID = 5, FirstName = "Ahmed", LastName = "ali", City = "Pwe", FatherName = "Hasan khan", PhoneNo = "--", Status = false });
            listEmployee.Add(new Employee() { ID = 6, FirstName = "Bill", LastName = "gate", City = "new jersey", FatherName = "--", PhoneNo = "--", Status = true });



            return listEmployee;
        }
```

and then call it as

```
dataGrid1.ItemsSource = populatedlistEmployee();
```